# Difference between Apply {} and Apply {items:...}?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have been using Ext.Apply in my InitComponent like so

```
  Ext.apply(that, {
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [.....
```

But i noticed there was a blue background left behind on my window where the xtype is used, basically using the following fixes the issue. I suppose I am asking what the difference between the two is ?

```
  Ext.apply(that, {
        items: {
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [
```

If you notice that the first one I am just applying xtypes directly on the Apply and the 2nd one (that fixes the issue) I am including the array items.

Which one should i be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first `apply` you are applying the `form` onto 'that' itself, with the second `apply` you are applying the `form` on the `items` array. But to make it more confusing you should use [`applyIf`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext-method-applyIf) to ensure you are not overriding existing items in the array.

```
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: {
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [
                ...
            ]
        }
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Here you can find more info about apply in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply